# Surface Area Of A Paraboloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the surface area of a paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ which is between $z=0$ and $z=2$

The approach I taken is to evaluate straight using surface integral.

First we will write the field as:

$$F=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r^2)$$

next the normal:

$$n= 
    \begin{vmatrix} 
    \hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}\\
-r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta&0\\
\cos\theta&\sin\theta&2r\end{vmatrix}=(2r^2\cos\theta, 2r^2\sin\theta,-r)$$

$$\int \int F\cdot \hat{n} ds=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r^2)\cdot (2r^2\cos\theta, 2r^2\sin\theta,-r)= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}(2r^3-r^3)dr d\theta=\\=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}r^3dr\cdot2\pi=2\pi$$

a. Is it correct?

b. How/Can we use stokes on the curve $x^2+y^2=2$ to evaluate the surface area?

Comment: I don't think it's true. The area of the disk $x^2+y^2\le2$ is already $2\pi$ but the surface area you want to calculate is obviously larger than the disk.

Comment: $F$ is a parametric representation of the surface, it is not a field

Comment: You should calculate the integral of $|n|,$ not $F\cdot n$